# How do I stop the swift playground for a long running process?

Tags: swift, swift-playground

Hope this is not a dumb question, as I can't find it anywhere.

I program in Swift playground and have a long process running. It's already compiled and running (I can see the log showing). How can I stop the process?

The only way I found so far is by killing the entire Xcode.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Found it. I always run from the left line numbering where I click the play. Apparently, on the lower panel, there's a play and stop button there as per picture below.

[image]